# Why use DrawerLayout instead of a CoordinatorLayout behavior for NavigationView

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library

I have been looking into the implementation of `DrawerLayout` and I started to wonder why the Android Support Library team chose to make a new layout instead of creating a new `Behavior` for `CoordinatorLayout` to be placed into the 'NavigationView'. Same goes to `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Is there any particular reason why they decided to implement in this way?

Answer (score 0):

To what I remember that CoordinatorLayout was introduced later to that of Drawer layout. And as per my knowledge and understanding Drawer Layout was introduced to put options using menu file onto the drawer following all the mentioned design guidelines by default.

If we talk about Coordinator layout, it's main work is to adjust other UI components within it due to some changes of any of the co-UI component of the layout.

So if you talk about adding behaviour of drawer layout to Coordinator layout, it won't suit to Coordinator's layout work. As per UI, drawer layout is shown outside the main Layout i.e. outside the coordinator layout. Also, nothing gets adjusted when drawer layout Thus it can't be part of Coordinator layout.

Comment: "As per UI, drawer layout is shown outside the main Layout i.e. outside the coordinator layout." DrawerLayout is not a UI to be shown at all, the `NavigationView` is a UI. When the `NavigationView` moves other views does get adjusted. For instance, the toolbar icon may animate so there is a dependent relation between one of the children (the `NavigationView`) and the other `Toolbar`. But even if it did not, there is nothing requiring a dependency relation, it just supports, in fact, the `BottomSheetBehavior` does not have by default any dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Everything indicates that there's no technical particular reason to use `DrawerLayout` instead of a `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior`. Reading its implementation is almost like reading a Behavior implementation.

In fact, the implementation of Side Sheets, which pattern is basically the same sheet that a drawer, [seems that it will be implemented as a Behavior](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/91), like the `BottomSheetBehavior`.

`CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` was introduced in version 24.1.0 and `DrawerLayout` in version 22.1.0, so maybe they understood that the `DrawerLayout` could be generalized but didn't want to deprecate it and spend more time on the same pattern, but this just a guess.